# Is it possible to debug objects in python?

Tags: python, debugging

Python. Let's say I define a class and in a script I create an object using that class.
Then I run a method and I get an error.
Can I use a debugger (for example Spyder's) to understand what is going on inside? for example inserting break points in the class definition?

**UPDATE**

I'm using spyder debugger.
My script looks like this

```
...
#I select the object class I need
ObjectClass = GetTheRightClass(variable) 

#my object is initialized with variable1
my_object_instance = ObjectClass(variable1) 

#I perform a calculation with my object
calculation = my_object_instance.calculate() 
...
```

If I place a break point inside the definiton of the method calculate() the debugger doesn't stop there...

Comment: You can put a breakpoint in a method, just like any other code. Did you have some reason to think otherwise? Did something go wrong when you tried?

Comment: yes, there are multiple debuggers for python. pdb is usually included in the distribution and python IDEs typically have them too.

Comment: I'm using Spyder debugger and it doesn't seem to be able to do it...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible in multiple IDE's.

For python, a cool project is also [pysnooper](https://github.com/cool-RR/PySnooper). If you call the method using the class you want, you can put a decorator `@pysnooper` before that function.
If you run the script, you can visually debug the code.